# Amazon MQ - Avoid Using Message Selectors

Tags: activemq-classic, amazon-mq

Amazon documentation advises [against using JMS selectors](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/latest/developer-guide/connecting-to-amazon-mq.html#avoid-using-message-selectors):

> **Avoid Using Message Selectors**
>
> It is possible to use JMS selectors to attach filters to topic
> subscriptions (to route messages to consumers based on their content).
> However, the use of JMS selectors fills up the Amazon MQ broker's
> filter buffer, preventing it from filtering messages.
>
> In general, avoid letting consumers route messages because, for
> optimal decoupling of consumers and producers, both the consumer and
> the producer should be ephemeral.

I consider JMS selectors a very useful and legitimate feature. I don't quite understand the statement about the "filter buffer." Can someone please clarify the details of the "filter buffer" issue? Is this a common problem for ActiveMQ Classic, or is it specific to the Amazon MQ service implementation? Additionally, is there a way to mitigate this issue through configuration tuning?

Comment: I've never heard of this "filter buffer" issue with ActiveMQ Classic, but that doesn't mean it isn't a real problem (although I have my doubts). I know for a fact that it's not an issue with ActiveMQ Artemis.

Comment: Thanks, Justin. While digging into the documentation, the only issue I found with the use of selectors is related to conduit subscriptions. It's described in the ActiveMQ documentation in the section "Conduit subscriptions and consumer selectors." here : https://activemq.apache.org/components/classic/documentation/networks-of-brokers#:~:text=Conduit%20subscriptions%20and%20consumer%20selectors,messages%20are%20dispatched%20to%20consumers. But I'm not sure if AmazonMQ is using conduit subscriptions in their default broker configurations.

Comment: There's nothing in the Classic docs about any "filter buffer" issue with JMS selectors. I couldn't even find anything with a web search except the Amazon MQ docs and this post on Stack Overflow. I don't recall ever seeing anything about it on the ActiveMQ users mailing list. For what it's worth, I've never seen anybody from Amazon answer a question about Amazon MQ here on Stack Overflow so you should probably work directly with them to see what exactly the issue is all about. It would be great if you could follow-up here if you get an answer from them to your question.

Comment: It seems like Amazon just copy pasting this statement from one manual to another since at least 2019.

Answer (score 0):

There is validity to the advice, the doc is incomplete and lacks full context. Yes, all message brokers have an 'unmatched filter' scenario that can lead to stalled out message flow-- specifically in the slow-consumer-on-a-topic scenario.

When a topic has multiple consumers, and one is slower than the others the topic must keep messages for that one slow consumer at the risk of stalling out the other consumers by having to keep all those messages in memory. This behavior can be modified in ActiveMQ by closing slow consumers, or applying a SubscriptionStrategy to start not delivering messages to the slow consumer as to not impact the other consumers.

Any message flow pattern that includes performing a 'queue-in-a-queue' design runs the risk of undesirable side-effects. This goes for queues and topics. Generally, it is more resilient to filter messages to separate queues per subscriber vs using patterns like like Message Groups, selectors, etc.

ActiveMQ's Virtual Topics allow consumers to register a filter using a selector and then each subscriber gets their own queue with only messages that they want. This is the best of both-- apps can use selectors, avoiding 'queue-in-a-queue' and avoiding 'slow-consumer' causing back pressure.

Comment: Matt, thanks for your response. Could you clarify how selectors relate to the issue of slow consumers? From what I understand, slow subscribers causing message buffering doesn't seem directly impacted by selectors. In fact, using selecors might even improve performance by filtering out unnecessary messages and so reducing a number of messages to be stored. Could you explain further?

Comment: Additionally, there's a problem with using Virtual Topics: selectors on the consumer side don't support durability. This means that if the subscriber is offline, any messages sent during that time will be lost. While there's a plugin available to address this, it relies on an external file for storage. I'm not certain if or how this is supported by the AmazonMQ service.

Comment: @spoonboy This is not correct. ActiveMQ supports storing the selector to support when the subscriber is offline.

Comment: @spoonboy the issues isn't unique to selectors, it is when one consumer on a topic with multiple subscribers is slower than others.  Selectors can make this scenario bubble up more frequently.

Comment: Matt, the documentation says that as long as selectorAware is set to true, the persistence is lost and the plugin needs to be used to provide the persistence: "When selectorAware=true, only active consumers are considered for selector matching. If consumers disconnect and reconnect they will miss messages" (https://activemq.apache.org/components/classic/documentation/virtual-destinations).

Comment: As well, I specifically tested that all messages published to a topic are copied to the Consumer's queue when selectorAware=false despite the filter matching.

Comment: @spoonboy keep reading.. further down the page it specifies if you add the VirtualSelectorCacheBrokerPlugin plugin that selectors are saved when consumers are offline.

Comment: Hi Mat, yes, I know about the plugin. That's why I specifically mentioned it in my comment: "While there's a plugin available to address this, it relies on an external file for storage. I'm not certain if or how this is supported by the AmazonMQ service". I logged another question specifically for this matter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78164628

Comment: I need to add that as the plugin is not mentioned in the permitted configuration elements, I doubt that it could be actually used with AmazonMQ: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/latest/developer-guide/permitted-elements.html