# How to use virtualSelectorCacheBrokerPlugin with Amazon MQ service

Tags: activemq-classic, amazon-mq

We aim to implement the `virtualSelectorCacheBrokerPlugin` on the [AmazonMQ service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/latest/developer-guide/working-with-activemq.html) to preserve selectors during subscriber outages, as outlined in the [ActiveMQ Classic documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/classic/documentation/virtual-destinations).

However, the plugin necessitates specifying the external file location in the `persistFile` parameter e.g.

```xml
<virtualSelectorCacheBrokerPlugin persistFile="<some path>/selectorcache.data" />
```

Could someone please advise on the appropriate value to use for this parameter with the Amazon MQ service? It's worth noting that Amazon doesn't disclose the internal file system details of the service instance; only the storage type (e.g., Amazon Elastic File System) can be seen in the service configuration.

Update: I doubt that the plugin can actually be used with AmazonMQ as it is not mentioned in the [permitted configuration elements for Amazon MQ](https://:%20https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/latest/developer-guide/permitted-elements.html).